# I cant store image on firebase if dont connect with wifi? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I can store image with android phone on firebase, if I connected on WiFi, but if don't connected I can't save image.

```
error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pickapp-b9a6b.appspot.com/o?name=f3418342-acc0-459b-bca7-a365d2c9f626&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UqtvcU9MorOeJqDIQG3072nF0mr-4V1Ygrt5us4zgvnP_7gEZI-poyho8dXckMMPDAFcw7YQUftQZkWGCVoe7JINswASA&upload_protocol=resumable
java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 405
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeTunnel(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:517)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
at bzr.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:368)
at bzr.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:246)
at bzr.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:270)
at bzl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:53)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajq$zza$zza.zziL(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajt.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzVj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: So what's the question? You do realize Firebase is a "Cloud" services provider and therefore you need an Internet connection to communicate with it.

Comment: I have mobile Internet so i don't know why can't upload image with mobile connection without wifi.

Comment: You should be able to upload with a mobile connection without any extra code. Do you have a data plan activated on the phone? Try testing your app with another device.

Comment: Yes I test with some phone, and its the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly kind of amazed that you got a `405` back, since AFAIK, we (GCS) don't return a `405` (see [GCS error codes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes)). Could this be an issue with a proxy or firewall preventing you from uploading, or changing your request?

Comment: I don't have any proxy, is very rare cause, if the mobile is connected on wifi, that issue does not appear.

Comment: 405 is defined in this [GCS document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#405method-not-allowed).  Is it for an interface not related to this processing?